# Blazor Webassembly: How to insert components into a string

Tags: localization, blazor, web-component, webassembly

I have this component that displays generic messages:

```
<span>@message</span>
```

The messages are identified by an `id` and come from string tables in resources files (multiple languages). An example of a message would be:

```
"Hello {user}! Welcome to {site}!"
```

So in the basic case, I simply parse the string and replace `{user}` with, say, "John Doe" and `{site}` with "MySiteName". The result is set to `message` and is then properly (and safely) rendered.

But what I would like to do is actually replace {site} with a *component* that I created that displays the site name with special font and styling. I also have other cases where I want to replace special `{markings}` with *components*.

How would you approach this problem ? Is there a way to "insert" a component into a string and then insert the string "safely" to be rendered ? I say "safely" because portions of the final string may come from the DB and be inherently unsafe (like user's name) so inserting the string with something like `@((MarkupString)message)` does not seem safe.

**EDIT**:
Thanks to MrC aka Shaun Curtis from whom this final solution is greatly inspired. I marked his answer as the best one.

So I finally went with a scoped service that gets the strings from the resources files, parse them and return a list of RenderFragments that it gets from a component's static table. I use dynamic objects to send specific parameters to the RenderFragments when required.

I basically now get all the text of my app through this centralized mechanism.

Here is an example of an entry in a resource file string table:

```
Name: "welcome"; Value: "Welcome to {site:name} {0}!"
```

Here is how it is used in a component:

```
<h3><Localizer Key="notif:welcome" Data="@(new List<string>() { NotifModel.UserNames.First })"/></h3>
```

You can see the simplified component and service code below. I explicitely left out the validation and error checking code for simplicity.

```
@using MySite.Client.Services.Localizer
@inject ILocalizerService Loc 

@foreach (var fragment in _fragments)
{
  @fragment.Renderer(fragment.Item)
}

@code
{
  private List<ILocalizerService.Fragment> _fragments;

  public enum RendererTypes
  {
    Default,
    SiteName,
    SiteLink,
  }

  public static Dictionary<RendererTypes, RenderFragment<dynamic>> Renderers = new Dictionary<RendererTypes, RenderFragment<dynamic>>()
  {
    // NOTE: For each of the following items, do NOT insert a space between the end of the markup and the closing curly brace otherwise it will be rendered !!!
    //                                                       Like here ↓↓
    { RendererTypes.Default, (model) => @<span>@(model as string)</span>},
    { RendererTypes.SiteName, (model) => @<MySiteNameComponent />},
    { RendererTypes.SiteLink, (model) => @<a href="@model.LinkUrl">@model.LinkTxt</a>}
  };

  [Parameter]
  public string Key { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public List<string> Data { get; set; }

  protected override void OnParametersSet()
  {
    _fragments = Loc.GetFragments(Key, Data);
  }
}

interface ILocalizerService
{
  public struct Fragment
  {
    public Fragment(RenderFragment<dynamic> renderer)
      : this(renderer, default)
    {
    }

    public Fragment(RenderFragment<dynamic> renderer, dynamic item)
    {
      Renderer = renderer;
      Item = item;
    }

    public RenderFragment<dynamic> Renderer { get; set; }
    public dynamic Item { get; set; }
  }

  List<Fragment> GetFragments(string key, List<string> parameters);
}

internal sealed class LocalizerService : ILocalizerService
{
  private readonly Dictionary<string, IStringLocalizer> _strLoc = new Dictionary<string, IStringLocalizer>();

  public LocalizerService(IStringLocalizer<MySite.Shared.Resources.App> appLoc,
                          IStringLocalizer<MySite.Shared.Resources.Connection> connLoc,
                          IStringLocalizer<MySite.Shared.Resources.Notifications> notifLoc)
  {
    // Keep string localizers
    _strLoc.Add("app", appLoc);
    _strLoc.Add("conn", connLoc);
    _strLoc.Add("notif", notifLoc);
  }

  public List<Fragment> GetFragments(string key, List<string> parameters)
  {
    var list = new List<Fragment>();

    GetFragments(list, key, parameters);

    return list;
  }

  private void GetFragments(List<Fragment> list, string key, List<string> parameters)
  {
    // First, get key tokens
    var tokens = key.Split(':');

    // Analyze first token
    switch (tokens[0])
    {
      case "site":
        // Format : {site:...}
        ProcessSite(list, tokens, parameters);
        break;

      default:
        // Format : {0|1|2|...}
        if (uint.TryParse(tokens[0], out var paramIndex))
        {
          ProcessParam(list, paramIndex, parameters);
        }
        // Format : {app|conn|notif|...}
        else if (_strLoc.ContainsKey(tokens[0]))
        {
          ProcessStringLocalizer(list, tokens, parameters);
        }
        break;
    }

  }

  private void ProcessSite(List<Fragment> list, string[] tokens, List<string> parameters)
  {
    // Analyze second token
    switch (tokens[1])
    {
      case "name":
        // Format {site:name}
        // Add name component
        list.Add(new Fragment(Shared.Localizer.Renderers[Shared.Localizer.RendererTypes.SiteName]));
        break;

      case "link":
        // Format {site:link:...}
        ProcessLink(list, tokens, parameters);
        break;
    }
  }

  private void ProcessLink(List<Fragment> list, string[] tokens, List<string> parameters)
  {
    // Analyze third token
    switch (tokens[2])
    {
      case "user":
        // Format: {site:link:user:...}
        ProcessLinkUser(list, tokens, parameters);
        break;
    }
  }

  private void ProcessLinkUser(List<Fragment> list, string[] tokens, List<string> parameters)
  {
    // Check length
    var length = tokens.Length;
    if (length >= 4)
    {
      string linkUrl;
      string linkTxt;

      // URL
      // Format: {site:link:user:0|1|2|...}
      // Retrieve handle from param
      if (!uint.TryParse(tokens[3], out var paramIndex))
      {
        throw new ApplicationException("Invalid token!");
      }
      var userHandle = GetParam(paramIndex, parameters);
      linkUrl = $"/user/{userHandle}";

      // Text
      if (length >= 5)
      {
        if (tokens[4].Equals("t"))
        {
          // Format: {site:link:user:0|1|2|...:t}
          // Use token directly as text
          linkTxt = tokens[4];
        }
        else if (uint.TryParse(tokens[4], out paramIndex))
        {
          // Format: {site:link:user:0|1|2|...:0|1|2|...}
          // Use specified param as text
          linkTxt = GetParam(paramIndex, parameters);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        // Format: {site:link:user:0|1|2|...}
        // Use handle as text
        linkTxt = userHandle;
      }

      // Add link component
      list.Add(new Fragment(Shared.Localizer.Renderers[Shared.Localizer.RendererTypes.SiteLink], new { LinkUrl = linkUrl, LinkTxt = linkTxt }));
    }
  }

  private void ProcessParam(List<Fragment> list, uint paramIndex, List<string> parameters)
  {
    // Add text component
    list.Add(new Fragment(Shared.Localizer.Renderers[Shared.Localizer.RendererTypes.Default], GetParam(paramIndex, parameters)));
  }

  private string GetParam(uint paramIndex, List<string> parameters)
  {
    // Proceed
    if (paramIndex < parameters.Length)
    {
      return parameters[paramIndex];
    }
  }

  private void ProcessStringLocalizer(List<Fragment> list, string[] tokens, List<string> parameters)
  {
    // Format {loc:str}
    // Retrieve string localizer
    var strLoc = _strLoc[tokens[0]];

    // Retrieve string
    var str = strLoc[tokens[1]].Value;

    // Split the string in parts to see if it needs formatting
    // NOTE:  str is in the form "...xxx {key0} yyy {key1} zzz...".
    //        This means that once split, the keys are always at odd indexes (even if {key} starts or ends the string)
    var strParts = str.Split('{', '}');
    for (int i = 0; i < strParts.Length; i += 2)
    {
      // Get parts
      var evenPart = strParts[i];
      var oddPart = ((i + 1) < strParts.Length) ? strParts[i + 1] : null;

      // Even parts are always regular text. If not null or empty, we add directly
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(evenPart))
      {
        list.Add(new Fragment(Shared.Localizer.Renderers[Shared.Localizer.RendererTypes.Default], evenPart));
      }

      // Odd parts are always keys. If not null or empty, get fragments recursively
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oddPart))
      {
        GetFragments(list, oddPart, parameters);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just checking before I put together an answer: Is component in "replace {site} with a component" a Blazor Component?

Comment: The "safety" concerns suggest you want to store HTML in the backend and render it. Please elaborate about the extent of the input/output .

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes, blazor component. For example <SiteNameComponent />

Comment: @HenkHolterman No, I am not storing HTML in the backend. Simply user provided strings such as their name. I mentioned security just because I am concerned that if the solution to my problem implies using "MarkupString" (or something along the line), the user provided strings could endup being rendered without validation. For example if the user said their name was "<script>...</script>", just want to make sure the possible solutions take into account the fact that I obviously do NOT want this to become actual HTML !

Comment: OK, that's just displaying text then. How 'configurable' should eg the User field be?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? My hunch is that you have XY problem. Can you please elaborate further on the user case? For example, if you simply want to show {user} in a formatted way, you can use CSS variables; you don't need a separate component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to build components.  A component is a c# class that emits a `RenderFragment`.

You could simply build `RenderFragments` for {site},...  Here's a simple static class that shows two ways to do this:

```
namespace StackOverflowAnswers;

public static class RenderFragements
{
    public static RenderFragment SiteName => (builder) =>
    {
        // Get the content from a service that's accessing a database and checking the culture info for language
        builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "p-2 bg-primary text-white");
        builder.AddContent(2, "My Site");
        builder.CloseElement();
    };

    public static RenderFragment GetSiteName(string sitename) => (builder) =>
   {
       // parse to make sure you're happy with the string
       builder.OpenElement(0, "span");
       builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "p-2 bg-dark text-white");
       builder.AddContent(2, sitename);
       builder.CloseElement();
   };
}
```

And here's an index page using them:

```
@page "/"
@using StackOverflowAnswers

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class=m-2>
The site name for this site is @(RenderFragements.GetSiteName("this site"))
</div>

@(RenderFragements.SiteName)
```

With the `RenderFragment` your writing c# code.  You can run a parser to check the string before rendering it.

You could have a scoped service that gets the info from the database for the user and exposes a set of `RenderFragments` you then use in your pages/components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really pointed me in the right direction with RenderFragments. My final solution (see edit in OP) is greatly inspired by your solution which I will mark as the answer. However I did not use the builder as in your answer; I instead directly stored the renderfragments in a static table. My service then uses this table to build a render fragments list.

Answer (score 1):

I used regex to split the source at the tokens configured in `TokenMappings`. Token mappings could easily be loaded from a json source for example. To configure more "`{markings}`" just add more lines to the `TokenMappings`.

```
<StringParser Source="Hello {user}! Welcome to {site}!" />
```

`StringParser.razor`

```
@foreach (var subString in substrings)
{
    if (tokens.Contains(subString))
    {
        var key = StripCurlyBrackets(subString);
        <DynamicComponent Type=@(TokenMappings[key].Item1) 
                          Parameters=@(TokenMappings[key].Item2) />
    }
    else
    {
        @subString
    }
}

@code {
    private Dictionary<string, (Type, Dictionary<string, object>?)> TokenMappings;
    private string[] substrings;
    private string[] tokens;

    [Parameter]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        var user = "John Doe";       // I would expect these are supplied via a signin context.
        var site = "MySiteName"; //  

        TokenMappings = new Dictionary<string, (Type, Dictionary<string, object>?)>
        {
            { "user", ( typeof(UserComponent), new Dictionary<string, object>{ { "User", user } } ) },
            { "site", ( typeof(SiteComponent), new Dictionary<string, object>{ { "Site", site } } ) }
        };

        var keys = TokenMappings.Keys.Select(a => a);
        var pattern = keys.Select(key => $"({{(?:{key})}})").Aggregate((a, b) => a + "|" + b);
        this.substrings = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(Source, pattern);
        this.tokens = TokenMappings!.Keys.Select(key => $"{{{key}}}").ToArray();
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }

    private string StripCurlyBrackets(string source)
    {
        return source
            .Replace(oldValue: "{", newValue: string.Empty)
            .Replace(oldValue: "}", newValue: string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Yes MarkupString allows you to render html.

`substrings :`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Although I did not quite went that way, your answer pointed my in the right direction as far as splitting the string into tokens and treating each of them individually. But from there, I went the RenderFragments as pointed out in @MrC aka Shaun Curtis' answer. You can see my final solution in an edit of the OP.